# Android sending post data to webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services, https

Hi I'm trying to send data to a webservice

String url = "https://www.myurl.com";

```
    URL urlobj =  new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) urlobj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    String urlParameters = GenerateUrlParameters(data);

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);

    Log.i("test", "hit1");

    DataOutputStream  wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

    Log.i("test", "hit2");

    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);

    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
```

Hit1 is hit but it fails in the next line and doesn't hit hit2. What am I doing wrong ?

My logcat

```
10-18 09:17:33.302: D/gralloc_goldfish(2228): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-18 09:17:33.322: W/TextLayoutCache(2228): computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run
10-18 09:17:37.862: I/test(2228): hit1
10-18 09:17:37.872: D/AndroidRuntime(2228): Shutting down VM
10-18 09:17:37.872: W/dalvikvm(2228): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3034)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     ... 11 more
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:280)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at dk.example.epaypayment.EpayHttpRequest.MakePayment(EpayHttpRequest.java:53)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at dk.example.epaypayment.MainActivity.sendMessage(MainActivity.java:37)
10-18 09:17:37.912: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     ... 14 more
10-18 09:22:38.232: I/Process(2228): Sending signal. PID: 2228 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please google that Exception android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call `sendPostRequest(String username, String pass)` method with parameters. You can call this method from the UI thread, the request will be sent from a different thread (`AsyncTask` is embedded).

```
private void sendPostRequest(String givenUsername, String givenPassword) {

    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String paramUsername = params[0];
            String paramPassword = params[1];

            System.out.println("*** doInBackground ** paramUsername "
                + paramUsername + " paramPassword :" + paramPassword);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                "http://lib-dm.process9.com/libertydm/ValidateUserHandler.ashx");// replace with your url
            httpPost.addHeader("Content-type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair(
                "UserId", paramUsername);  // Make your own key value pair
            BasicNameValuePair passwordBasicNameValuePAir = new BasicNameValuePair(
                "Password", paramPassword);// make your own key value pair

            // You can add more parameters like above

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairList.add(usernameBasicNameValuePair);
            nameValuePairList.add(passwordBasicNameValuePair);

            try {
                UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                    nameValuePairList);
                httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

                try {
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient
                        .execute(httpPost);
                    InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity()
                        .getContent();
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                        inputStream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        inputStreamReader);
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String bufferedStrChunk = null;
                    while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                    }

                    return stringBuilder.toString();

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                        System.out
                            .println("First Exception coz of HttpResponese :"
                                + cpe);
                        cpe.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        System.out
                            .println("Second Exception coz of HttpResponse :"
                                + ioe);
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                System.out
                    .println("An Exception given because of UrlEncodedFormEntity argument :"
                        + uee);
                uee.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(givenUsername, givenPassword);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing this code ,it should work. 
And if your Android version is above 4.0, then you will have to compulsory use Asyn Task , So that this http request do not run on Main Thread. otherwise app will crash.
  If the app is using HTTPGET or HTTPPOST method and is running on Main Thread ,it will crash. Asyn TAsk is the Solution.

```
   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url1);

    try {
        json.put("Key","your value");
        json.put("Key", "Value");


        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(json.toString());

        stringEntity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
        stringEntity.setContentType("application/json");
        post.setEntity(stringEntity);

        response = client.execute(post);
        Log.e("RESPONSE", response.toString());
        String responseBody = EntityUtils
                .toString(response.getEntity());
         res= responseBody.toString();

        Log.e("RESPONSE BODY", responseBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could suggest to do it in little higher abstraction, using HttpClient.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;

HttpParams my_httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(my_httpParams);
```

and then sending

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(stringUri);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpPost.setHeader("charset", "utf-8");

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(someStringToSend)) {
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(someStringToSend, HTTP.UTF_8));
}

HttpResponse responsePOST = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();

if (resEntity != null) {
    response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
}
```

I have not tested it but should work.